# VBA - How to find maximum value among grouped values with a specific clause condition [SOLVED]

Tags: excel, vba

[image: snapshot]

I have this data table with 4 columns.

I have to get the maximum value of a SEQUENCE each time a value for ERGO TYPE is given as a parameter.

For example, Ergo Type = 'E04', MaxVal = 2 ; Ergo Type = 'E07', MaxVal = 1 ; Ergo Type = 'E11', MaxVal = 2

I think there is a way not using a loop because that could be a bit tricky to loop among all surrounding datas when the focus is on a sub group.

In term of Query, it's as if to use Group by keyword and Where clause for parameter. But here we are with excel.

Any suggestions to implement this case ?

Thank you for helps.

Comment: If you have Excel 365, you can simply use dynamic arrays. For instance: `=MAXIFS(A2:A100,B2:B100,UNIQUE(B2:B100))`

Comment: Thank you @Paul. Yes I use Excel 365. Do you have an idea how to introduce only one value as a filter ?

Comment: For a single value in cell F1, it is =MAXIFS(A2:A100,B2:B100,F1).